# iOS Google Map Dynamic Zoom

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have a Google Map that's plotting a set of locations closest to the current GPS. How do I let the Map automatically zoom to just enough so that I can see the 5 closest locations in the map (but not anything bigger)

Answer (score 0):

This is the implementation using MapKit and MKAnnotations. If you're using the Google Map SDK you just need to change the logic to use GMSMarkers and the related APIs instead.

```
// Zoom Map to Fit Annotation
    MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;
    for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations) {
        MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
        MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1);

        if (MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect)) {
            zoomRect = pointRect;
        }
        else {
            zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
        }
    }

    [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2) animated:YES];
```